# SpecFlow test execution based on a feature file parsed during runtime

Tags: testing, runtime, specflow

Well the topic already states my questions,
Is it possible to parse a Feature File during runtime and
execute it afterwards?

Comment: So, for example, you'd like to load a `.feature` file into memory - perhaps into a `string[]` of lines of the file, and then execute one or more scenarios from it?  Am I understanding you?... And can you expand on why you want to do it, because there may be other approaches we could take?

Comment: Yes, thats what I want to achieve. The idea behind this approach is to create a simply click'n'try testing suite for UIs.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, ut does this help at all? http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/